# Wanted 'LibrarySystem.ctrlSeparator' file in C# .Net

Tags: c#, file-io

I want this file ('LibrarySystem.ctrlSeparator') to run my project in C#. Can anyone tell me a solution to get this file. This file is needed for my library management project.

Comment: Please **don't** cross post. Here's the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808293/unable-to-open-my-project-in-c-net

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect this is a custom library developed by whoever you got the solution from.

I suggest you ask *them* for the library. The only references on the web are your other posts.